# How I can Add multiple select clause to list in asp.net dynamically at run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have page in asp.net ,in this page there is check boxes .
I should select many check box then on button click it should go to the relevant list and select the checked items from the class below.
so what  I need is to build add select clause at run time.

this the model:

```
     public class UserInfo 
     {
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserNameLogin { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
     }
```

and this is the list:

```
  static List<Models.UserInfo> _List_UserInfo = new List<Models.UserInfo>();

public void LoadUserInfo()
    {                                                                                                                        
      _List_UserInfo   =  Controllers.UserInfoController.GetUserInfo(Utility.GetDatabaseConnection());

    }
```

then the selection of items fro the list should be like that:

```
       _List_UserInfo   =_List_UserInfo   .select(x=>x.UserNameLogin );
```

but the point that i need the selection for multiple items and at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Just select all the data. Unless one of the columns is a file there is no problem in getting the full user info.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SampleConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class UserInfo
        {
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public string UserNameLogin { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public bool IsActive { get; set; }
            public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
            public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        }

        public class UserInfoSubset
        {
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public string FullName { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Assuming you loaded all information you needed from database.
            var myList = new List<UserInfo>();

            // Anonymous selection.
            var subset1 = myList.Select(x => new
            {
                x.UserID,
                FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName)
            }).ToList();

            // Strong type selection.
            var subset2 = myList.Select(x => new UserInfoSubset
            {
                UserID = x.UserID,
                FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName),
                Email = x.Email
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```